# Another word for ‘an easy source of income’ or ‘an easy job’?

Tags: word-request

I swear I knew this English word but no longer remember. There is a rarely used single word (rare in newspapers/articles that I read) that means *’an easy source of good income that does not require much effort’* in other words *‘an easy job’*. What is that word?

Comment: Perhaps a [plum job](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Plum%20Job), as defined by Urban Dictionary: "An easy and pleasant job that also pays well." (note that the other unrelated definitions on that page are quite vulgar...)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe *Sinecure*:

[AHD *sinecure*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=sinecure)

a position or office that requires little or no work but provides a salary.

[From Medieval Latin (beneficium) sine cūrā, (benefice) without cure (of souls) : Latin sine, without + Latin cūrā, ablative of cūra, care; see CURE.]

Comment: Thanks Jack! Lord Bless! That was it.